# SignalR client (Xamarin forms) doesn't get data when sending to a specific group

Tags: xamarin.forms, notifications, signalr

I am having an issue where I would like to send a massage to specific user
Server:

```
        public async Task JoinGroup(string group)
        {
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId,group);

        }
```

Controller :

```
public async void SendToClient(){
  await DashboardHub.Clients.Group("g1").SendAsync("Test","hi from controller");

}
```

Xamarin:

```
hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("url server/dashboardHub")                
                .Build();

            await hubConnection.StartAsync();
            await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("JoinGroup", "g1"); // Failed to invoke 'JoinGroup' due to an error on the server. 
// await hubConnection.SendAsync("JoinGroup", "g1");

hubConnection.On<long, string>("Test", (msg) =>{
// code here that received the data from server
}
```

the same solution was working when controller send the data to all users like this

```
  await DashboardHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("Test","hi from controller");
```

but this solution not working to send data to a specific group and user.

thanks in advance